# Innovation Science 2 Theme,Thumbnails Images Are Not Generated

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, thumbnails, image-resizing

I am installing a wordpress theme innovation science 2 (from Digital Cavalary) for [my gaming portal](http://spiceygames.com/).

I'll understand the whole theme functions but I have a problem with thumbnails on posts and pages.

Thumbnail images on my site are not generated properly, loading icon is spinning and the image is not loading.

Whenever I click on spinning thumbnails, image will be opened but thumbnails not showing. I guess there is no problem with images, its about images resizing or thumbnails generating.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide some code from the theme? Especially the index.php and the functions.php. It feels like there is a method that extracts the image from each post and uses that image to generate the thumbnail. For some reason it is failing to identify the image to extract and resize.